# SQL Subquery or Join?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Desired result is to have all patients that have more than 1 allergy displayed with their PatientId (From Patient table, NOT Allergy table) and PatientName

2 Tables:

- Patient table contains PatientId (Represented as P_), PatientName.
- Allergy table contains PatientId (Represented as p_), AllergyName.

So far, I have 2 queries that I want to connect together but dont know how:

```
    SELECT PatientId, PatientName
    FROM Patient;

    SELECT COUNT(AllergyName)
    FROM Allergy
    GROUP BY AllergyName
    HAVING COUNT(AllergyName) >1;
```

I want to complete a calculation in the "background" without it being shown in the table. PatientId's are the same, just that for Patient table it is an uppercase P and lowercase p for Allergy table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT PatientId, PatientName
FROM Patient INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as allergy_count, PatientId
        FROM Allergy
        GROUP BY PatientId
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1) aggr ON Patient.PatientId=aggr.PatientId
```

Comment: It says that i need to enter a parameter for the query, and if it does run, won't it create a 3rd column called allergy_count, the result that i am expected to get should just be the PatientName and PatientId

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT PatientId, PatientName from (
SELECT PatientId, PatientName, (SELECT COUNT(AllergyName)
    FROM Allergy A
    WHERE A.PatientId= P.PatientId
    GROUP BY patientID 
    HAVING COUNT(AllergyName) >1)
    FROM Patient P)
```

Comment: What i need is just the PatientId and PatientName, not the allergy count, the query should work out who has more than 1 allergy and get that name and id only, not display the count

Comment: Updated for you

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are asking for:

```
SELECT Patient.PatientId, Patient.PatientName
FROM Patient
INNER JOIN Allergy ON Patient.PatientId = Allergy.patientId
GROUP BY Allergy.patientId
HAVING COUNT(Allergy.AllergyName)>1;
```

EDIT:

> all patients that have more than 1 allergy displayed with their
>   PatientId (From Patient table, NOT Allergy table) and PatientName

I guess from that you don't need to display the count.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should solve the purpose for you:

```
SELECT P.PatientID, P.PatientName from Patient P
JOIN Allergy A ON A.PatientID = P.PatientID
GROUP BY A.AllergyName
HAVING COUNT(A.PatiendID) > 1
```

Inner queries can cost you performance degrade in case of large datasets so joins are recommended to optimise query performance.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you require only patient id and name the below query is suitable for your requirement.

[image: I hope this would work]

Comment: Consider changing image to text. Web browsers can't read from image.